# Get last user that modify an object

Tags: libgit2

Thank to the libgit api, I can get the Object corresponding to my entry in the tree.
- Get the last commit (git_reference_peel)
- Get the tree (git_commit_tree)
- Get the tree entry (git_tree_entry_bypath)
- Get the object (git_tree_entry_to_object)

I wonder if there is a way to get the author/signature of the last user who has make a change on this object.

The signature of the commit doesn't my requirement

Best Regards
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

The libgit2 API allows you to retrieve the identity of the person that performed the last changes on an object. However, that requires to orchestrate the calls according to the following algorithm.

Revwalk the history and perform diffs between the current commit and its parents until the file you're tracking is detected as changed. Once the commit is isolated, retrieve the identity of the author of this commit.

In order to provide you with a quick start, I'd suggest you to get some inspiration from the code of **[pull request #1965](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1965/files#diff-bf215f5c1a0413eac59f304ffc86b6f2)** that demonstrates how to do this.